# How to download fpdf output file in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, fpdf

I am trying to direct download the generated file by fpdf.output('myfilename.pfd','D') in the browser using Django view. 
for single python file it works properly but I am unable to do it into the Django view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your view:

```
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='file_name.pdf'"
return response
```